# What does the *movies* word mean

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the *movies* word mean in the following statements?

> - If you went to the **movies**, I would babysit.
> - If only I had more money, I could go to the **movies** too.

Does it mean *cinema* or *theater*?

> **movies**: the showing of movies at a theater. [Cambridge Dictianary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/movies)

but the definition isn't clear to me. it is look like the word is verb.

Comment: Almost all English nouns can be verbed. The word *movies* comes from *moving pictures*.

Comment: It is a plural noun from the singular **movie**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. Going to the movies means going to the theater where movies are shown (to see a movie).

Answer (score 0):

It is a plural noun from the singular **movie**.

The singular **movie** refers to an individual film, such as *Jurassic Park*.

In the plural, **movies** can refer either to more than one film

> That director makes pretty good movies.

or to the screening of movies as a form of entertainment that one can attend:

> Would you like to go to the movies this weekend?

That could be paraphrased, "Would you like to go to a movie theater this weekend, to see a movie?"

Comment: How people can go to movies? I can understand go to cinema. can people go to books?! but they can go to library.

Comment: @Shannak You can't think of it literally. You have to accept that it's an idiom.